# Why do shebangs and commands from certain scripts (python, perl, libtool) are wrongly interpreted by bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, interpreter, shebang

**EDIT : this problem is still there : I rebuilt my entire system and the chroot I use for it on a sane host works like a charm. But once I boot the same target system, the problem appears again: shebang for perl and python are wrongly interpreted...**

I've been building and administrating my own Linux system successfully for about 4 years but I'm kinda stuck now and I'd appreciate very very much to get directions to fix that hellish problem:

Some Python, Perl scripts or even commands from within 'configure' scripts are misinterpreted: I've identified python-config, xscreensaver-text and intltool-merge (Perl scripts) whose Shebangs are not respected or are only interpreted by the shell.

We've been messing around with locales, encondings, considerations about UTF-8, checking env, $LANG, $TERM and such, switching Linux kernels (3.1.5, 3.5.4, 3.8.1, 3.11.1), but still no success.

Here is the strace output from xscreensaver-text, first with a simple call form the CLI then a second call with explicit Perl. Its shebang is:

```
#!/bin/perl -w

root@poopy:~# strace /usr/bin/xscreensaver-text
execve("/usr/bin/xscreensaver-text", ["/usr/bin/xscreensaver-text"], [/* 32 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
write(2, "strace: exec: Exec format error\n", 32strace: exec: Exec format error
) = 32
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++

root@poopy:~# strace perl /usr/bin/xscreensaver-text
execve("/usr/bin/perl", ["perl", "/usr/bin/xscreensaver-text"], [/* 32 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x601000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd74eb1d000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=198969, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 198969, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd74eaec000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1868472, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3981888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd74e52f000
mprotect(0x7fd74e6f1000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fd74e8f1000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c2000) = 0x7fd74e8f1000
mmap(0x7fd74e8f7000, 16960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd74e8f7000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd74eaeb000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd74eae9000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fd74eae9740) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd74e8f1000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd74eb1e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fd74eaec000, 198969)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x601000
brk(0x622000)                           = 0x622000
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd74eae9a10) = 16061
wait4(16061, poopy
Linux 3.11.1

ven. 27 sept. 2013 14:06:27 CEST

up  2:17,  1 user
load average: 0,03, 0,06, 0,12

[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 16061
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=16061, si_status=0, si_utime=2, si_stime=0} ---
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

My PATH is:

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/lib64/jdk/bin:/usr/lib64/jdk/jre/bin`

It is on an x86_64 system with i686 multilib capabilities.
My locale is fr_FR.utf8 ($LANG and $LC_ALL). I will add any info you guys will need.
My shell in '/etc/passwd' is '/bin/bash', it exists and works flawlessly.
Tried with normal users and root, no difference.
Bash 4.2, linux 3.11.1, glibc 2.17. Tried in xterms, xfce-terminal and ttys, same problem.

The 'python-config' or 'intltool-merge' (and many others) have exactly the same behaviour. I even saw once a 'configure' script failing with the message "ac_cv_somevariable: command not found". Any idea where to look for debugging this?

Thanks.

Comment: It could be that the path is not valid, or accessible to the user executing the file. For example, on some systems `sbin` is only accessible to root, and applications are installed in `/usr/bin/` vs. `/bin`.

Comment: Thanks Burhan, but the $PATH seems correct -added to question) and I explicitly called the file with an absolute path. My /bin and /sbin dirs are symlinks pointing to /usr/bin and /usr/sbin, BTW.

Comment: Could we get the first 10 bytes or so of broken perl script from a hex editor?  `od -N=10 -x perlscript.pl`

Comment: @ebyrob here they are:`od -N 10 -x /usr/bin/xscreensaver-text` says: `0000000 2123 752f 7273 622f 6e69
0000012`

Comment: 7 0's?  No FE FF or FF EF?  Any idea what the encoding is or how the OS would know it?  21 23 looks like ASCII, but !# instead of #!?  (Oh, 0000000 and 0000012 are addresses)  Is it normal for ASCII to be reverse-endian?

Comment: What are the sources of these scripts? Are the copied from another system, or you are just downloading stuff?

Comment: @ebyrob Thanks for your comment. So the problem seems definitely to be my encoding. `locale` returns `fr_FR.utf8`. How could I dig it a bit more?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid this scripts comes from upstream xscreensaver package, I build 1400+ packages on this system before starting having those problems.

Comment: UTF8 is just ASCII with longer characters above 7F where appropriate.  As far as I know it wouldn't flip on 16-bit endian-ness or otherwise change byte order.  (Maybe something got confused along the way processing as UTF16 or UTF32?)

Comment: Yes, I don't see why my encodings seem so weird, it nevr has been a problem before (fr_FR.UTF-8 is my locale for 4 years, `unicode_start` on the console does not say anything).

Comment: Have you made any changes to the system before this problem occurred? You say you are using a 64-bit system, have you changed to this system recently?

Comment: If you download these scripts again do they still have this problem?

Comment: See domen's comment below, the bytes are in the right order.

Comment: You might have a BOM (byte order mark) at the beginning of the file if you've edited the file, especially if the file originated in another encoding/locale.  What is the result of running `file` on the problem scripts? You should get something along the lines of `Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable`

Comment: @GavinSmith the files are OK, they've been successfully built and used on a previously generated system (I build my own Linux system for years, as in LinuxFromScratch and Cross-LFS).

Comment: @JimR: yes we looked at that too but no success so far. `file` returns this before AND after editing with vim: `/usr/bin/xscreensaver-text: awk script, ISO-8859 text`. Weird, huh ? :-)

Comment: Do the /bin and /sbin symlinks have the necessary file permissions?

Comment: @GavinSmith the /usr/{,s}bin are root:root 755 and the symlinks /{,s}bin are OK (777, both pointing to 'usr/bin' or 'usr/sbin')

Comment: @user2369816: Yes, weird.  ISO-8859 is essentially ASCII as I understand it and should be a subset of UTF-8, again as I understand it.  I don't think encoding is the problem any longer. :).  I'd guess it's time to try another shell if you haven't already done so.  zsh is a nice alternative to bash...  Also, look to see if anything is in LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: @JimR I just tried to build a package with dash, and still the same (intltool-merge (a Perl script) is interpreted as a shell script and dies).

Comment: @user2369816: Is there anything in the LD_PRELOAD env variable?

Comment: awk script? That's fishy. For the "#!/usr/bin/perl" version, please include the outputs of: `head -n 1 /usr/bin/xscreensaver-text | hexdump -C`, `uname -m` and `file /usr/bin/perl`.

Comment: The Perl executable is normally `/usr/bin/perl`, not `/bin/perl`. If a script with `#!/usr/bin/perl` doesn't work when you execute it, does typing `/usr/bin/perl script-name` at the command line work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Linux 3.10 a new option called CONFIG_BINFMT_SCRIPT must be set to Y if you want your kernel to handle interpreted scripts.

More explainations here :
http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/BINFMT_SCRIPT.html

If you compiled it as a module, try to modprobe the binfmt_script module and then test your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

instead of

```
#!/bin/perl
```

?

Comment: I edited xscreensaver-text (though it is an upstream file from xscreensaver package), and nothing changed. *BUT* I noticed that my vim editor prints weird #F and #H chars when I hit the Home or End keys, so I guess I got a problem there...

Comment: Yes, this also caught my eye. @user2369816, please include strace for the `#!/usr/bin/perl` version. And `ldd /usr/bin/perl`.

Comment: @domen ok with `#!/usr/bin/perl -w` in `xscreensaver-text` we have: `execve("/usr/bin/xscreensaver-text", ["/usr/bin/xscreensaver-text"], [/* 50 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
write(2, "strace: exec: Exec format error\n", 32strace: exec: Exec format error
) = 32
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++`

Comment: @domen `ldd` shows `linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe1129000)
 libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe7b2b5e000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe7b2f2b000)`

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED!**

The kernel has a new option since 3.10: CONFIG_BINFMT_SCRIPT. It was compiled as a module here, so non-loaded by default! Loading the module with `modprobe binfmt_script` or building the kernel with `CONFIG_BINFMT_SCRIPT=y` fixes the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This analysis is WRONG.**  `od -x` outputs "short converted (2 byte) ints".
I thought it was outputting `od -xC` which would be all bytes in network order.

Quick analysis of the binary dump:

```
2123 752f 7273 622f 6e69  // hex bytes
! #  u /  r s  b /  n i

!#u/rsb/ni     // condensed
#!/usr/bin     // 2-flipped
#!/bin/perl -w // question line
```

My guess would be the problem isn't on your system, but with encoding and interpretation on one of the systems between yours and the public repository on-line for each of these files.

Sniffing the files as they're downloaded might help?  (hopefully you can find something unencrypted, you could also check a binary dump at each machine hop)

**EDIT:** Vim keys should be fixed by a corrected `/etc/inputrc` in most cases.  If not (and you're not using zsh) then it could be related.

Comment: Weird, it is as if the file is being interpreted as UTF-16 (or another 16-bit encoding) and written to disk with the wrong byte order.

Comment: That's just the way "od -x" works `$ echo '#!/usr/bin' | od -x:
0000000 2123 752f 7273 622f 6e69 000a`

Comment: @domen Ack!  Talk about a blind alley.  Should I delete or leave as a cautionary tale?  I guess -xC was what I was after.

Comment: I'd leave it with some note on the top.

Comment: @domen I do have a correct inputrc! :) I use the same for years. `file` show it as Unicode UTF-8 text and vim seems to not care about it. UTF-8/encoding seems to be my main and biggest problem...